# Error C2059 syntax error: 'public'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm getting this error "Error C2059 syntax error: 'public'" in the first "public" of the HelloWorld.h file when I try to build the project. Looks like it's expecting something else but I'm a rookie on this. I have also tried using ref instead of __gc as the new syntax rules.

Does anybody have a clue of what can be missing here?

Thanks in advance.

HelloWorld.h

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "CSharpHelloWorld.netmodule"

using namespace System;

public __gc class HelloWorldC
{
    public:
        // Provide .NET interop and garbage collecting to the pointer.
        CSharpHelloWorld __gc *t;
        HelloWorldC() {
            t = new CSharpHelloWorld();
            // Assign the reference a new instance of the object
        }

     // This inline function is called from the C++ Code
        void callCSharpHelloWorld() {
            t->displayHelloWorld();
        }
};
```

Comment: Neither `ref` nor `__gc` are C++. One is C++/CLI, the other is Managed Extensions for C++. Are you sure you're compiling as one of those?

Comment: Probably just omit `public` here: `public __gc class HelloWorldC`

Comment: @SebastianRedl To be honest with you I have no clue. I am trying to create a wrapper for a c# dll (.netmodule) to use in java.

Comment: @EdChum I'm not sure. Check previous comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Won't that make the class inaccessible?

Comment: @Neikon In standard c++ at least all classes in their namespaces are publicly accessible.

Answer (score 2):

1. use `ref class` instead of `__gc class` in line 6
2. use `^` instead of `__gc *` in line 10
3. use `gcnew` instead of `new` in line 12 change
4. Common Language Runtime Support To (/clr) in `your project Properties`

Comment: The reason is that __gc is the old syntax...and in VS2017 that doesn't even work.  But the old way will compile with clr old syntax set in VS2010.